# Start android camera from a python program via Bluetooth

Tags: android, python, bluetooth

I want to create a small python program that will run on my computer and will connect via Bluetooth to my smartphone.

The idea is to have already open the video camera app and will receive a signal for start recording and stop to record.

My plan is to use PyBluez for connecting via Bluetooth to the smartphone. My big doubt is what signal to send, any idea where I can find this type of information?

Comment: I sense a lack of research in this question. There is no default mechanism for a bluetooth signal to activate any app. You would need to to write your own Android app to perform the activities you describe.

Comment: Probably you're right on lack of research. But how does the selfie stick or Bluetooth controllers work? I just open the default camera app and press a button on the control and it works, no Android app is working, just the normal camera

Comment: A quick search leads to this article which covers the basics of the selfie stick: http://www.howtogeek.com/207102/ask-htg-why-does-my-selfie-sticks-shutter-button-zoom-my-camera/ For other Bluetooth devices like keyboard/mouse there is Bluetooth HID support in Android.

Comment: I found that article, and the theory is great! When you press the button of the selfie stick it sends a signal to the camera. The signal is the press down volume. How do I send this signal is what concern me

Comment: I got it know, I need to found the command key of the volume button or power on button and send this signal using the python library